# Getting started with vue - no data is showing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Im following the vue documentation. and i have setup the next code

```
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="app">
                <ol>
                    <li v-for="todo in todos">
                        {{ todo.text }}
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ constant('JS_URL') }}lib/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                todos: [
                    { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
                    { text: 'Learn Vue' },
                    { text: 'Build something awesome' }
                ]
            }
        });
    </script>
```

my output looks like this:

```
    <div id="app">
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

I dont understand this. it is looping 3 times but not showing the data. All the other examples from their documentation have the same result. Im dont know why this is happening.

I have other libaries included on the page also like jquery but my console is showing no errors.. it only shows the vue message that we are running in development mode.

Also the first example of their page just displaying a message doe not work... what am i doing wrong? (im using the latest version)

Comment: ahhh... i found the error. im using in in combination with twig (php template engine) wich also uses {{ .........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using TWIG template engine for php wich also uses {{ }} notation so i changed the vue delimiters like this:

```
            var app2 = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['${', '}'],
```